# How do I find the value of $x$ in this equation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The equation is
$$\dfrac{1}{a}+b+x=\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b}+\dfrac{1}{x}$$

I've tried
$$\require{cancel}\dfrac{1+ab+ax}{a}=\dfrac{bx+ax+ab}{abx}\\abx(1+ab+ax)=a(bx+ax+ab)\\\cancel{abx}+a^2b^2x+a^2bx^2=\cancel{abx}+a^2x+a^2b\\a^2b^2x+a^2bx^2=a^2x+a^2b$$

But, don't understand how to solve further. Can somebody show step by step please. Thanks!

Comment: My first step would be to subtract $\frac{1}{a}$ from both sides...

Answer (score 3):

You are on the right track, then you have

$bx^2+x(b^2-1)-b=0$

You solve the quadratic equation for x and you get: $x=\dfrac{1}{b}$ or $x=-b$

Answer (score 2):

Since

$$\dfrac{1}{a}+b+x=\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b}+\dfrac{1}{x}\quad\iff\quad b+x=\frac1b+\frac1x\quad\iff\quad x^2+\left(b-\frac1b\right)x-1=0$$
Factorization give us
$$\left(x+b\right)\left(x-\frac1b\right)=0$$
Thus $x=-b$ or $x=\frac1b$.

Answer (score 2):

subtracting $$\frac{1}{a}$$ on both sides we have $$b+x=\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{x}$$ then we have $$x-\frac{1}{x}=\frac{1-b^2}{b}$$ and after multiplying by $$x$$ we have
$$x^2-\frac{1-b^2}{b}x-1=0$$ you Need to use the quadratic equation formula additionally it must be $$a,b,x\ne 0$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\dfrac{1}{a}+b+x=\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b}+\dfrac{1}{x}$$
Take the LCM at right side
$$\Rightarrow\dfrac{1}{a}+b+x=\dfrac{ab+ax+bx}{abx}$$
$$\Rightarrow abx\bigg(\dfrac{1}{a}+b+x\bigg)=ab+ax+bx$$
$$\Rightarrow bx+ab^2x+abx^2=ab+ax+bx$$
Take $x$ common from first two terms and last two terms
$$\Rightarrow x(b+ab^2)+abx^2=ab+x(a+b)$$
Subtract $ab+x(a+b)$ from both sides
$$\Rightarrow -ab-x(a+b)+x(b+ab^2)+abx^2=0$$
Simplifying it we get
$$\Rightarrow -ab+x(ab^2-a)+abx^2=0$$
Rewrite it
$$\Rightarrow abx^2+(ab^2-a)x-ab=0$$
It’s a quadratic equation so, factoring out it we get
$$\Rightarrow a(bx^2+b^2x-x-b)=0$$
$$\Rightarrow a(bx(x+b)-1(x+b))=0$$
$$\Rightarrow a(b+x)(bx-1)=0$$
$$x=\dfrac{1}{b}$$
$$x=-b$$

Answer (score 1):

cancel $\dfrac1a$ from both the sides
 now we have $$b+x=\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{x}$$ take L.C.M $$x+b=\frac{x+b}{xb}$$ $$x+b\left(1-\frac{1}{xb}\right)=0$$ from here $$x=-b~,~x=\frac1b$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
\dfrac{1}{a}+b+x&=\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b}+\dfrac{1}{x}\\
b+x&=\frac 1b+\frac 1x\\
x-\frac 1x&=\frac 1b-b=-\left(b-\frac 1b\right)\\
\color{red}{x}&\color{red}{=\frac 1b, -b}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

We begin by cancelling terms and expanding both sides individually and then multiplying each by the LCM.

\begin{align*}
\dfrac{1}{a}+b+x
&=\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b}+\dfrac{1}{x}\\
 \\
b+x&.  =\dfrac{b+x}{bx}\\
b^2x+bx^2&  =b+x\\
bx^2 + (b^2-1)x-b &  =0\\ 
\\x. &= \dfrac{-(b^2-1)\pm\sqrt{(b^2-1)^2-4(b)(-b)}}{2b}\\
&= \dfrac{1-b^2 \pm \sqrt{b^4 + 2 b^2 + 1} }{2 b}
\\&= \dfrac{1-b^2 \pm (b^2 + 1) }{2 b}
\\& = \frac{1}{b}\space\text{ or }\space\frac{-b}{1}
\end{align*}